# Using a component as a parameter for a ngx-translate key

Tags: html, angular-material, ngx-translate

I'm using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) in my project. I want to use an Angular Material component (mat-form-field), as part of the translation's value.
Example:

Key: `NumberChoice`

Value: `Choose a number: {{choice}}.`

Use in the  HTML:

```html
    <span>{{ 'NumberChoice' | translate: {choice: this.choiceSelectorComponent} }}</span>
```

`choiceSelectorComponent` is the mentioned above mat-form-field.

I tried putting the code for the mat-form-field in a new ng component and defined a getter for it in the matching `.ts` file.

I also tried to get it as an HTML tag like so:

```js
 get choiceSelectorComponent() {
    return document.createElement('page-size-selector').outerHTML;
    }
```

Which only made the tag be part of the translation:

> Choose a number: <page-size-selector></page-size-selector>.

In other words, how can I include UI controls inside a translated value dynamically, using them as parameters to pass to `ngx-translate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `ngx-translate` [documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core), you should do the following.

In your HTML template:

```
<span>{{ 'NumberChoice' | translate:choice} }}</span>
```

And in your component file you define param:

```
param = this.choiceSelectorComponent() // Or whatever value you want
```

This will allow the pipe to determine the value of the parameters correctly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps a lot. Might not work without some adjustments, but overall it's what I needed to help me solve this.